# How to save array of object in sprig boot with crudrepository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am very new to Spring boot and this is my first spring dummy project where I'm trying to learn to save an array of objects in mysql-db.

Actually, I am trying to use the saveAll method from the crudRepository in my controller. But it's giving me an error `no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that Iterable<S> conforms to List<User>`

My JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "Jack",
        "last_name": "Jill",
        "email": "jacjill@gmail.com",
        "password": "passq3623"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Doe",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "password": "pass23"
    }
]
```

This is my entity class

```
package com.example.testbatch.Entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

Here is my User Model Class

```
package com.example.testbatch.Models;

public class User {
    public int id;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String email;
    public String password;
}
```

Here is my repository

```
package com.example.testbatch.Repositories;

import com.example.testbatch.Entities.UserEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<UserEntity, Integer> {
    @Override
    List<UserEntity> findAll();

}
```

and here is my rest controller

```
package com.example.testbatch.Controllers;

import com.example.testbatch.Entities.UserEntity;
import com.example.testbatch.Models.User;
import com.example.testbatch.Repositories.UserRepository;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.T;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;



    @PostMapping("/register")
    public void saveUsers(@RequestBody UserEntity userEntity) {
        List<User> persistedUser = userRepository.saveAll(List.of(userEntity));
    }


}
```

Can anyone please help me? This is ery first time I am usig spring boot

Comment: `userRepository.saveAll(List.of(userEntity))` returns a list of type `UserEntity` and not `User`. You would need to map `UserEntity` to `User`, or just not care about the result. This depends on what you want to do with the data after saving

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Actually I just want to save this list to DB and return just a string "ok" as a response. Can you please please tell me how to save this list to db? I have no idea as of now :'(

Comment: Remove `List<User> persistedUser =` and you are good to go. For the response, wrap the `saveAll` call in a `try-catch`. If you catch any exception, then the save failed, otherwise it was successful

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Hi I just tried as you suggested but it's giving me an error ```Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.example.testbatch.Entities.UserEntity'```  Am I still missing something?

Comment: Are you sure it happens on the `userRepository.saveAll(List.of(userEntity));` call? I found this which has the same error as you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52634362/inferred-type-s-for-type-parameter-s-is-not-within-its-bound-should-extend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some problems about your code:

At first you have a *DTO* (`User` class), so, you should use this *DTO* inside your controller in `saveUsers` method and more importantly **you pass an array of objects in your JSON, so you have to use a `List` not an `Object` as the parameter**:

```
public void saveUsers(@RequestBody List<User> users) {...}
```

Another problem is you don't have any `getters` and `setters` inside you DTO (`public class User`) and Entity (`public class UserEntity`) classes and also you have to add a method inside your *DTO* class for **mapping** *DTO* to *Entity*:

```
public class User {
    ...
    public static UserEntity dtoToEntity(User user){
        UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        userEntity.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        userEntity.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userEntity.setFirst_name(user.getFirstName());
        userEntity.setLast_name(user.getLastName());
        return userEntity;
    }
}
```

Also you must change your JSON properties to match your DTO's properties:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Jack",
        "lastName": "Jill",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

As the last one, change your controller `saveUsers` method as (saveAll method return `Iterable` not `List`):

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public void saveUsers(@RequestBody List<User> users) {

    List<UserEntity> userEntities = new ArrayList<>();

    for (User user : users) {
        userEntities.add(dtoToEntity(user));
    }

    Iterable<UserEntity> persistedUser = userRepository.saveAll(userEntities);
}
```

***Notice:*** As a point remember that because you have auto-generated id inside your *Entity*, so you don't need id property for your *DTO*, obviously because it's auto-generated and you don't need to get it from input;

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me :D. I wasn't aware of DTO that much just learnt from you. :)

Answer (score 1):

The user_repo is returning a List of type UserEntity
while in yout controller you are asking for a   List of type User

There is not mapping between UserEntity and User.